# Looking for snowman hands

Tags: material-selection, technique-selection

I have an Avon Brilliant snowman lamp. Last Christmas I realized that his acrylic arms are missing. I have called several craft stores and Avon regarding replacement arms with no avail. I was hoping to get some direction to find some replacements on this exchange.

Comment: Are you looking to craft your own replacements?

Comment: No, I would not know where to begin

Answer (score 3):

eBay lists a few 2001 Avon Brilliant Snowman lamps. One of them has a price of about seven fifty plus about sixteen dollars shipping.

My first suggestion would have been to commission a 3D printed version, using clear resin and SLA printing, but the model creation and printing would have exceeded the eBay cost of a complete unit.

Of course, you're going to have a full lamp plus the parts remaining from your existing lamp.

Additionally, if you are sufficiently crafty, you can use the new/used lamp to silicone mold the arms and pour clear acrylic to create an additional set of arms.

This would likely be the most cost effective method, especially since you can create the mold without damaging the originals.

Comment: Thank you. I will check selling websites

Comment: "silicone mold the arms and pour clear acrylic to create an additional set of arms" has me picturing a snowman with a dozen arms like a statue of Kali.

Comment: One might also consider Calvin and Hobbes and his maniacal snow creatures!